# .NET - How to rename a Desktop icon so it doesn't move position

Tags: c#, .net, icons, desktop, rename

Is there an easy way to rename a Desktop icon without it moving position? Everytime File.Move is called, the icon jumps to the default position based on the users Deskop organization selection (Date or Name, etc.).

This is annoying to users who are not tech savvy. They arrange their icons meticulously, and to have them jump around EVER is disturbing to them.

Comment: Yeah, this is by design. If you rename an item in a list sorted alphabetically, it would be broken if that item's order in the list didn't change. Think about what you're asking for more carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something that can be solved programmatically.  Desktop icon arrangement is a user setting.  You can, however, educate users of your program how to easily find your application using things like Quick Launch.

Comment: +1 And if you do find a way to do it programmatically, you shouldn't :)

Comment: It seems odd that everyone seems against doing this . . . I have users that are not very good with their computers (but are good with using the features of the computer they are used to), and this is very bad for them. This seems like it should be a no-brainer. Yeah, it's not a big deal for you or me, or any of the programmers on this site, but put yourself in the shoes of a user using a tool to do their job, and the tool changes, and suddenly you don't know what to do about it. Good software is about making the user's life easier, transitioning silently, being transparent to the task.

Comment: @Richard: I don't think anyone is claiming that user inexperience isn't a problem.  It's just not a problem that can be solved in C# with *your program*.  Educating users in using Windows is generally outside the scope of any particular program.  If, as you say, your users are meticulous in their placement of icons, you can probably count on them to have the settings necessary to keep them where they put them.

Comment: I get that. It just seems like this would be something that would have been included as an easy thing to do with the .NET framework. I hate to do this, but you did answer the question, so I will accept that at least at this time, you can't do it. Blah. But I do thank you for taking the time to answer me.

Comment: @richard two things: 1) it's unfortunately common to get blame-shifting responses when asking for something that isn't implemented. 2) the Windows desktop is unfortunately one of the least updated parts of Windows and suffers no end of design/UX problems. IMO it is one of the worst yet most widely used pieces of software in modern times (21st century, 2020s). What we have today is not much if any different than Windows 3.1 or even earlier.